# Cocoapod library and multiples configurations embedding

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

After googling a lot regarding my need, I finally ask to this awesome community a way to achieve my  goal.

I need to create a swift library with cocoapod, and integrate multiple build configurations. I want to create 3 schemes on my project to switch easily environments variables (like target API, log level, and many more).

I really want to do this on library side, not on app-side, since it's for debug & testing purposes, and finally, applications which embed this pod will only use the "Release" build (except us, developers who maintain this library)

I tried opening the _Pods.xcodeproj and doing update in this file (create *.xcconfig files I need, mapped to configurations schemes) but disappear after ran a "pod install".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure at all if you can do that hack on library side. Looks weird.

But the best practice would be:

When initializing and configuring libraries, endpoints etc (all you need to change between schemes), just check which one is used, and pass different parameters

create a file, FE Constants

```
struct Constants {
   static var libraryApiKey: String {
#if DEBUG
   return "debugKey"
#else
   return "productionKey"
}
```

And when initializing

```
Library.initialize(withKey: Constants.libraryApiKey)
```

Comment: Actually, I tried a bit similar way :
- Configuring multiple configurations in Project 
- Adding multiples xcconfig files for each env (DEV/UAT/PROD)
- Mapping my settings inside a Configuration.plist file with VALUE=${VALUE} 

But my point is : how can I keep theses configuration through my pod ?